# how can I sum array element in php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need this result:

```
breakfast: Monday, Tuesday, Thursday

lunch: Monday, Saturday

dinner: Tuesday, Sunday
```

From this array:

```
Array
(
[breakfast] => Array
    (
        [0] => Monday
        [1] => Tuesday
        [2] => Thursday
    )

[lunch] => Array
    (
        [0] => Monday
        [1] => Saturday
    )

[dinner] => Array
    (
        [0] => Tuesday
        [1] => Sunday
    )
)
```

How can i do?

Comment: Do you want `an array with comma separated values` or a `string`

Comment: `$new = array_map(function($i) { return implode(',',$i); }, $array);`

Comment: do you want the exact string representation of the result you are reffering to?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: array_count_values only counts

Answer (score 1):

try this,tak care about syntax error for array initializatiom

```
$a = Array
(
    [breakfast] => Array
    (
        [0] => Monday
        [1] => Tuesday
        [2] => Thursday
    )

    [lunch] => Array
    (
        [0] => Monday
        [1] => Saturday
    )

    [dinner] => Array
    (
        [0] => Tuesday
        [1] => Sunday
    )
);    


 foreach($a as $key => $val){
        echo $key . " : " . implode(",",$val)."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
      echo $key . ' : ' . implode(',',$value) .'<br />';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php